System.Text.Json deserializing-serializing numbers gives slightly-off numbers for some .NET versions
I have a test where a json with a number is deserialized, then serialized, then both jsons (original an deserialized-serialized) are compared for string equality. The project is built for net8.0 and net48/481.
When using dotnet test, I get the following results:

net8.0 passes; the original number 5.32 becomes 5.32.
net48/481 does not pass; the original number 5.32 becomes 5.3200000000000003.

When using the little Run Test button in VScode

I MOSTLY get a pass, but sometimes a fail (for the same number-related reason). In that case, closing VSCode, closing all dotnet.exe background processes, then reopening VScode resolves the issue usually. Unfortunately, I don't know a way to relaibly reproduce this issue.
Questions:

Why do net8.0 pass and net48/481 fail during dotnet test?
Why does the Run Test button sometimes give different results?
How do I make sure that any number deserialized from json is serialized to exactly that same number string?


Here are project file
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>net8.0-windows;net481;net48</TargetFrameworks>
    <LangVersion>10.0</LangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="17.6.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestAdapter" Version="3.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestFramework" Version="3.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="coverlet.collector" Version="3.1.2">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net48' Or '$(TargetFramework)' == 'net481'">
        <PackageReference Include="System.Text.Json" Version="8.0.4" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>

and test file
using System.Text.Json;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

[TestClass]
public class NumberSerializingTests
{

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestNumberSerializing()
    {
        var json = "{\"Number\":5.32}";
        var data = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyNumber>("{\"Number\":5.32}");
        var json2 = JsonSerializer.Serialize(data);
        Assert.AreEqual(json, json2);
    }
}

public class MyNumber
{
    public MyNumber(double number) { Number = number; }
    public double Number { get; }
}


If your code requires double values being "correct" (read: exact) to multiple decimal places: you're doing it wrong; that's not how floating point works - there may not even exist such a number (exactly) in floating point math! If you want "exact" numbers (in the human sense): use decimal, not double - fortunately, this should be data-compatible

The test is wrong to begin with. double is a floating point number. It's impossible to represent all numbers precisely and 5.32 is actually 5.32000000000000028421709430404007.... Try Console.WriteLine("{0:N18}",5.32d); in both runtimes

You can't compare floating point numbers directly, both due to representation issues and rounding errors. You can only check if their difference is less than a specific precision. The way floating point numbers are parsed from and formatted into strings are standardized and .NET Core 3.0 follows the standard more closely by generating the shortest roundtrippable string.

The fix for your requirements is simple:
    public MyNumber(decimal number) { Number = number; }
    public decimal Number { get; }

The reasons are covered in mine/Panagiotis's comments.
